# upgrading from 16.04 to 18.04 have left me in a login loop

Tags: gnome, upgrade, 18.04

pretty straight forward. whenever I enter my password correctly, it flashes to black and then return me to the login screen. I've googled this a lot and nothing have worked. when I run the command `sudo gnome-shell gnome` I get an error that says:

```
gnome-shell: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmutter-2.so.0: undefined symbol: wl_global_get_interface
```

I've found basically nothing about this error through google and was wondering if anyone here knows what's going on. is there a way to repair this?

Trying to reinstall libmutter-2-0:

```
karl@Bulbasaur:~$ sudo apt install --reinstall libmutter-2-0
Läser paketlistor… Färdig
Bygger beroendeträd
Läser tillståndsinformation… Färdig
0 att uppgradera, 0 att nyinstallera, 1 att installera om, 0 att ta bort och 41 att inte uppgradera.
Behöver hämta 1 205 kB arkiv.
Efter denna åtgärd kommer ytterligare 0 B utrymme användas på disken.
Läs:1 http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libmutter-2-0 amd64 3.28.3-2~ubuntu18.04.1 [1 205 kB]
Hämtade 1 205 kB på 0s (2 827 kB/s)
(Läser databasen ... 220135 filer och kataloger installerade.)
Förbereder att packa upp .../libmutter-2-0_3.28.3-2~ubuntu18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Packar upp libmutter-2-0:amd64 (3.28.3-2~ubuntu18.04.1) över (3.28.3-2~ubuntu18.04.1) ...
Ställer in libmutter-2-0:amd64 (3.28.3-2~ubuntu18.04.1) ...
Hanterar utlösare för libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSegFault.so is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmemusage.so is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcprofile.so is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libplds4.so is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetapi.so.0 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmirclient.so.9 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss3.so is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnssutil3.so is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libplc4.so is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl3.so is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsmbconf.so.0 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libminiupnpc.so.10 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnspr4.so is not a symbolic
```

Comment: If you press CTRL + ALT + F2/F3/F4 are you able to get to a text login?

Comment: @tudor no, not from the login screen. but if I stop the lightdm service I can get into text login and that works well. but I can also access it through ssh.

Comment: How did you upgrade to 18.04?  `lightdm` is no longer the default login manager, `gdm3` is.  Check to make sure that your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file all says "bionic" and not "xenial" and then try `apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: @tudor Ichanged to lightdm since gdm3 dosen't work for me for some reason. the service starts fine and all but a GUI never actually appear.

Comment: Fair enough, but it's much harder to find the reason behind a fault if you have made a change that is unusual to begin with and isn't done from knowledge-based reasoning.  We can only advise you based on the way the system is expected to work when the system has been set up a particular way.  Deviating from that is going to make finding an answer *really hard*.  Better to get back to as close to a default setup as possible and work from there.

Comment: I'm willing to try anything. but I've tried a lot of stuff. I can change back to gdm3 if you wish, bu it still dosen't explain why gnome crashes.

Comment: Can you please run `apt install --reinstall libmutter-2-0` and include the output in your question?

Comment: @tudor I understand. I reinstall the libmutter-2-0 and I posted the result in the question